# Multiple underscore templates in a single file with common values

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am having a template.html file like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="form-template">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="" id="company"
               value="<% if(typeof company!=='undefined') {%><%=company%><% } %>" placeholder="Company name">

</script>

<script type="text/template" id="person-template">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="" id="company"
               value="<% if(typeof company!=='undefined') {%><%=company%><% } %>" placeholder="Company name">

</script>
```

Now in the backbone view.js I have two views like this

```
var FormView = Backbone.View.extend({

 template: _.template($(formTemplate).filter("#form-template").html()),
 render:
 function(){this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON())}
});

var personView = Backbone.View.extend({

 template: _.template($(formTemplate).filter("#person-template").html()),
 render:
 function(){this.$el.html(this.template()}
});
```

When i render the form view, it works fine but when I render the person view, i get the fields pre-populated with value as "[object HTMLInputElement]" even if i pass nothing as the data.

The obvious guess is that both the templates are using <%=company%> but why that should be a problem if the templates are completely separate from each other?

Comment: It doesn't exactly make sense that your person template references a parameter, yet you pass no object into the template function. You haven't shown all of your code, but I'd guess that `company` is a variable that's in scope when you render the person view.

Comment: well thats what surprises me! This works fine if i wrap the company variable in some object like data.company in the person template. It is specifically a problem associated with the same variable name

Comment: @StephenThomas: beNerd has shown enough code. The problem is that Underscore templates use `with` and `<input id="x">` introduces `x` as a global variable via `window.x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. Both of your templates contain `id="company"` so you should expect odd things to happen when you put both templates on the same page. `id` attributes **must** be unique or you don't really have HTML anymore, you have something that sort of looks like HTML.
2. After you put `<input id="company">` in the page, you have a `window.company` property whose value is the DOM node for `<input id="company">`.

The second problem is what you're seeing but you should fix **1** anyway.

Underscore templates use JavaScript's [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) to allow an object to act like a scope. If `with` doesn't find the name (`company` in this case) in the supplied object (which will be `{}` in the second template), then it goes up the scope chain trying to find a variable called `company`. Since you have `<input id="company">` already in the DOM, `with` will find `window.company` as `company`. That leaves you with a DOM node in `company` and `typeof company` won't be `'undefined'` so your template throws a stringified DOM node on the page.

Consider this simplified example:

```
<script type="text/template" id="form-template">
    <input type="text" id="company"><br>
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="person-template">
    <%= typeof company %><br>
    <%= typeof company !== 'undefined' ? company : '' %>
</script>
```

and then a little JavaScript to mirror what your Backbone code is doing:

```
var f = _.template($('#form-template').html());
var p = _.template($('#person-template').html());

$('body').append(f());
$('body').append(p());
console.log(window.company);
```

You should see something like this on the page:

```
<input ...>
object
[object HTMLInputElement]
```

and a DOM node in the console.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/sRnuw/

This is a rather insidious problem with no clean solutions that I can think of. Possible options:

1. Make sure the `id`s on your form elements don't match any properties in your templates.
2. Make sure you supply all the properties to your templates, even empty ones. This will let you short-circuit the `with` before it goes looking for things in `window`.
3. Use the `variable` option to [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

   > By default, **template** places the values from your data in the local scope via the `with` statement. However, you can specify a single variable name with the **variable** setting.

   See the `_.template` docs for examples that use the `variable` option.
4. Switch to a better template system that doesn't use `with` trickery. I tend to use Handlebars.

Comment: What an answer! Thanks.